# Why does Windows 7 look for mouse drivers every time I plug in my USB mouse?

Tags: windows-7, usb

Every time I plug in my USB mouse (the same mouse each time), and a Microsoft mouse no less, Windows-7 (Pro) searches for mouse drivers and delays approx. 3-5 minutes before the mouse is functional.

How, if at all, can this be resolved?

This is basically a stock install with very little added software (malware is not the issue).

I usually use Linux on this device and, unsurprisingly, in Linux USB mice work instantaneously after being plugged in.

Comment: Windows has always had this issue, though it's the first time I hear about a mouse, usually it's with flashdrives. Reinstalling the driver might help. From device manager, right click on the mouse > properties > driver.